How role bases access works in spring 3.2.4?
I have created a spring boot project with spring boot version 3.2.4 and java version 17.
I am using spring security InMemoryUserDetailsManager for user management to secure my endpoints.
I want to restrict access to "/assignment/getGroceries" and "/assignment/order/**" to role USER only and admin can access rest all endpoints
below is my config class
package com.questionpro.testassignment.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password(encoder.encode("user"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User
                .withUsername("admin")
                .password(encoder.encode("admin"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/assignment/**")
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/assignment/getGroceries",
                                "/assignment/order/**")
                        .hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}

I am able to access all endpoints with admin but not able to access mentioned endpoints with user.
I am not getting what is wrong with this configuration. Could anyone please help on this?
Below are the logs when I tried to hit /assignment/order with user USER
2024-04-07T13:07:36.895+05:30  INFO 15660 --- [           main] c.q.t.TestAssignmentApplication          : Started TestAssignmentApplication in 15.588 seconds (process running for 17.738)
2024-04-07T13:07:36.897+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2024-04-07T13:07:36.902+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2024-04-07T13:08:22.256+05:30  INFO 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-07T13:08:22.256+05:30  INFO 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-07T13:08:22.257+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-04-07T13:08:22.257+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-04-07T13:08:22.257+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-04-07T13:08:22.259+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@467421cc
2024-04-07T13:08:22.259+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@47393345
2024-04-07T13:08:22.260+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-04-07T13:08:22.260+05:30  INFO 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2024-04-07T13:08:22.561+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2024-04-07T13:08:22.568+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-04-07T13:08:22.635+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-04-07T13:08:22.638+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Apr 07 13:08:22 IST 2024, status=403, error=Forbidden, path=/assignment/order}]
2024-04-07T13:08:22.718+05:30 DEBUG 15660 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403


Your request is faulty which makes spring redirect you to the /error endpoint. I suggest you read the chapter conveniantly named error management in the official spring boot docs.

@dur Thanks, It was issue with the order of requestMatchers. Its now working as expected :)
